# Only one table created sql Lite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I will created some table with DataHelper.java, but only one table created (location table), here my code

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "layerfarm-mobile.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String locationSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS location(id integer primary key, name text, address text, rid integer);";
    public static final String eqq_qualitySQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  eqq_quality(id integer primary key, name text);";

    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            //Create table
            db.execSQL(locationSQL);
            db.execSQL(eqq_qualitySQL);

        String InsertlocationSQL = "INSERT INTO location (id, name, address, rid) VALUES " +
                "(1,'Location A','Blitar',1)," +
                "(2,'Location B','Blitar',2)," +
                "(3,'Location C','Blitar',3)," +
                "(4,'Location D','Blitar',4);";
        db.execSQL(InsertlocationSQL);

        String InsertEggQualitySQL = "INSERT INTO egg_quality (id, name) VALUES " +
                "(1,'Quality A'), " +
                "(2,'Quality B'), " +
                "(3,'Quality C'), " +
                "(4,'Cracked');";
        db.execSQL(InsertEggQualitySQL);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop table if existed, all data will be gone!!!
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS location;"); 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eqq_quality;"); onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

create table and insert for location table is successfully, but other table is fail, the error log show here:

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: 
 egg_quality (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM egg_quality
```

how i can fix it?

thanks

Comment: try using eqq_quality instead of egg_quality (i.e. you have defined the table as eqq_quality not egg_quality)

Comment: Your table names are inconsistent. You're creating `eqq_quality` but you're inserting data into `egg_quality`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you have coded different table names. The table is created using eqq_table, whilst the query tries to access egg_table.

A way of reducing the potential for such mistakes is to define CONSTANTs for such values and to then always refer to the items (table names, column names, index names etc) via the respective CONSTANT.

As such I'd suggest changing :-

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "layerfarm-mobile.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String locationSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS location(id integer primary key, name text, address text, rid integer);";
    public static final String eqq_qualitySQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  eqq_quality(id integer primary key, name text);";

    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            //Create table
            db.execSQL(locationSQL);
            db.execSQL(eqq_qualitySQL);

        String InsertlocationSQL = "INSERT INTO location (id, name, address, rid) VALUES " +
                "(1,'Location A','Blitar',1)," +
                "(2,'Location B','Blitar',2)," +
                "(3,'Location C','Blitar',3)," +
                "(4,'Location D','Blitar',4);";
        db.execSQL(InsertlocationSQL);

        String InsertEggQualitySQL = "INSERT INTO egg_quality (id, name) VALUES " +
                "(1,'Quality A'), " +
                "(2,'Quality B'), " +
                "(3,'Quality C'), " +
                "(4,'Cracked');";
        db.execSQL(InsertEggQualitySQL);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop table if existed, all data will be gone!!!
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS location;"); 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eqq_quality;"); onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

to :-

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "layerfarm-mobile.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String TABLE_EGGQUALITY = "eqq_quality";

    public static final String COL_LOCATION_ID = "id";
    public static final String COL_LOCATION_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_LOCATION_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String COL_LOCATION_RID = "rid";

    public static final String COl_EGGQUALITY_ID = "id";
    public static final String COL_EGGQUALITY_NAME = "name";

    private String locationSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATION + "(" +
            COL_LOCATION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_LOCATION_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COL_LOCATION_ADDRESS + " TEXT," +
            COL_LOCATION_RID + " INTEGER" +
            ")";
    private String egg_qualitySQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EGGQUALITY + "(" +
            COl_EGGQUALITY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_EGGQUALITY_NAME + " TEXT" +
            ")";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created"); //????? Not correct as the database doesn't get created until an attempt is made to open it
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDB = db;

        /* USING TRY CATCH MAY CAUSE A GREAT DEAL OF CONFUSION
        try {
            //Create table
            db.execSQL(locationSQL);
            db.execSQL(eqq_qualitySQL);

            String InsertlocationSQL = "INSERT INTO location (id, name, address, rid) VALUES " +
                    "(1,'Location A','Blitar',1)," +
                    "(2,'Location B','Blitar',2)," +
                    "(3,'Location C','Blitar',3)," +
                    "(4,'Location D','Blitar',4);";
            db.execSQL(InsertlocationSQL);

            String InsertEggQualitySQL = "INSERT INTO egg_quality (id, name) VALUES " +
                    "(1,'Quality A'), " +
                    "(2,'Quality B'), " +
                    "(3,'Quality C'), " +
                    "(4,'Cracked');";
            db.execSQL(InsertEggQualitySQL);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
        db.execSQL(locationSQL);
        db.execSQL(egg_qualitySQL);
        insertLocation("Location A","Blitar",1);
        insertLocation("Location B", "Blitar",2);
        insertLocation("Location C","Blitar ",3);
        insertLocation("Location D","Blitar",4);
        insertEggQuality("Quality A");
        insertEggQuality("Quality B");
        insertEggQuality("Quality C");
        insertEggQuality("Quality B");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop table if existed, all data will be gone!!!
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATION);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EGGQUALITY); 
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * NOTE as ID column is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then SQlite will,
     * if no value is specified when inserting a row,
     * generate a unique value for the id column
     *  (initially 1, then likely 2, then likely 3 ......... )
     */
    public long insertLocation(String name, String address, long rid) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_LOCATION_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_LOCATION_ADDRESS,address);
        cv.put(COL_LOCATION_RID,rid);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_LOCATION,null,cv);
    }

    public long insertEggQuality(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_EGGQUALITY_NAME,name);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_EGGQUALITY,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllLocations() {
        return getAll(TABLE_LOCATION);
    }

    public Cursor getAllEggQuality() {
        return getAll(TABLE_EGGQUALITY);
    }

    public Cursor getAll(String table) {
        return mDB.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- other suggested improvements have been included
- NOTE if adding or changing tables the as the onCreate method only runs when the database is first created, you should either delete the App's Data, uninstall the App or increase the version number and then rerun the App (noting that all three methods would result in the loss of a data).

The above could be used, say in an Activity as follows :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DataHelper(this);

        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getAllLocations();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr = mDBHlpr.getAllEggQuality();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    }
}
```

The result of the dumpCursor's would be similar to :-

```
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@534aac14
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: 0 {
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    id=1
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    name=Location A
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    address=Blitar
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    rid=1
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: }
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: 1 {
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    id=2
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    name=Location B
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    address=Blitar
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    rid=2
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: }
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: 2 {
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    id=3
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    name=Location C
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    address=Blitar 
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    rid=3
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: }
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: 3 {
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    id=4
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    name=Location D
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    address=Blitar
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    rid=4
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: }
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: <<<<<
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@534c5e0c
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: 0 {
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    id=1
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    name=Quality A
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: }
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: 1 {
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    id=2
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    name=Quality B
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: }
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: 2 {
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    id=3
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    name=Quality C
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: }
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: 3 {
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    id=4
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out:    name=Quality B
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: }
12-12 04:32:23.854 1248-1248/so53700541.so53700541updatewithexpression I/System.out: <<<<<
```